# $\mathbb{P}\left(X\geqslant\frac{2\alpha}{\lambda}\right)\leqslant \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^{\alpha}.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

Using

$$\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant x)\leqslant e^{-tx}M_{X}(t),\text{ }t\geqslant0,$$

show that in the particular case that $X\overset{\underset{d}{}}{=}\Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)$,

$$\mathbb{P}\left(X\geqslant\frac{2\alpha}{\lambda}\right)\leqslant \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^{\alpha}.$$

I have only managed to get that $2\alpha/\lambda=2\mathbb{E}[X]$,

$$\mathbb{P}\left(X\geqslant2\mathbb{E}[X]\right)\leqslant\frac{M_{X}(t)}{e^{2t\mathbb{E}[X]}}=\frac{\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}\right)^{\alpha}}{e^{2t\mathbb{E}[X]}}$$

and

$$\mathbb{P}\left(X\geqslant2\mathbb{E}[X]\right)\leqslant\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the inequality
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X\geqslant2\mathbb{E}[X]\right)\leqslant\ \frac{\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}\right)^{\alpha}}{e^{2t\mathbb{E}[X]}}$$
take $t=\lambda/2$ to obtain the required bound.